# How to set height of <Linebreak />

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, text

Does anybody know how to set up height of `<LineBreak />` inside `<TextBlock />`? I tried to change font size of `TextBlock` but it's didn't help me.

**UPDATE**

I need to decrease it, not increase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<strike>The only way</strike> One of the possibility's that I can see are to use [FlowDocumentScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer.aspx) as the Content of your TextBlock. It will allow you to use a [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx) which has a [Paragraph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.paragraph.aspx) object which has FontSize and LineHeight Property's. This will give you the ability to change the Height of the LineBreak to a certain extent, this may not be as small as you want.

```xml
<Grid>
   <TextBlock LineHeight="1" Height="85" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,29,0,0" Name="textBlock1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Beige" >
        <FlowDocumentScrollViewer Width="400" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph LineHeight="1" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="Red" >
                    <Run> This is a Test of line height</Run>
                 </Paragraph>
                <Paragraph LineHeight="1" FontSize="1"  BorderThickness=" 1" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <LineBreak/>
                </Paragraph >
                <Paragraph LineHeight="1" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="Blue">
                    <Run> This is a Test of line height</Run>
                </Paragraph> 
                <Paragraph LineHeight="1" FontSize="2"  BorderThickness=" 1" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <LineBreak />
                </Paragraph>
                <Paragraph   LineHeight="1" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="Green" >  
                    <Run> This is a Test of line height</Run>
                </Paragraph>
                <Paragraph LineHeight="1" FontSize="5"  BorderThickness=" 1" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <LineBreak />
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

This gave me a result like this.

[image]

---

To add some additional information. I beleive most of the gap that you see between lines has to do with the LineHeight of the Text Lines. I played around with it a litte bit more and came up with this. It also has the added benefit of not needing a flow document.

```xml
<TextBlock LineHeight="9.75" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" Margin="12,188,-12,-188">
    <Run> This is a Test of Line Height</Run>
    <LineBreak />
    <Run >This is a Test of Line Height</Run>
    <LineBreak />
    <Run>This is a Test of Line Height</Run>
    <LineBreak />
    <Run> This is a Test of Line Height</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

This gave me a result that looks like this. It will allow you to go smaller than you could otherwise

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed solution. It's heavy so it doesn't approach for me: I just wanted two floor captions. So, instead of one TextBlock I used two in StackPanel.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, easiest workaround for me was to use a TextBlock for each line, give the TextBlock a bottom margin setting and contain them in a StackPanel.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,10">
        This is the text and this text is quite long so it wraps over the end of the line...
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,10">
        This is the text and this text is quite long so it wraps over the end of the line...
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

You can clean it up by putting the margin style in a shared resource.

Quick and dirty but it worked for my purposes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awful hack I came up with when faced with the same problem:

```
// close out paragraph and move to next line
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
var span = new Span();
// use a smaller size so there's less of a gap to the next paragraph
span.FontSize = 4;
// super awful hack. Using a space here won't work, but tab does
span.Inlines.Add(new Run("\t"));
// now the height of this line break will be governed by the font size we set above, not by the font size of the main text
span.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
textBlock.Inlines.Add(span);
```