# TextBlock Line Height

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to add a textblock control (with a determined height and width) to a canvas, and i want to set the line height property of that textblock according to the linespacing defined in font file (.tff). After loading the font file, i use a Typeface that has the properties off that font. Can anyone explain me why the line height is to big, and how i calculate a factor for each font and size, so that the line height allow all lines to fit in the textblock? I think the line height by default is not representing the true value of linespacing of the font file.

Here is the code, where item is my object:

```
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    tb.Width = item.SizePX.Width;
    tb.Height = item.SizePX.Height;
    tb.Foreground = color;
    tb.TextAlignment = item.TextFormat.TextHAlignment;
    tb.FontSize = item.TextFormat.FontSize;
    tb.FontFamily = typeFace.FontFamily;
    tb.FontWeight = typeFace.Weight;
    tb.FontStretch = typeFace.Stretch;
    tb.FontStyle = typeFace.Style;
    tb.TextDecorations = decCol;
    tb.MaxWidth = item.SizePX.Width;
    tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    tb.LineHeight = typeFace.FontFamily.LineSpacing * item.TextFormat.FontSize;

    tb.LineStackingStrategy = LineStackingStrategy.BlockLineHeight;
```

And `item.TextFormat.FontSize` is the size in pixels of the font defined in my object.

Then I tried with `typeFace.FontFamily.Baseline`:

`tb.LineHeight = ypeFace.FontFamily.Baseline * item.TextFormat.FontSize;`

Still not working... 
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: check this out

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208142/how-to-set-height-of-linebreak

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you're asking, please clearly explain. Why can you not use the normal/default height of the font characters? Are you trying to stretch the text in some way?

Comment: The problem is not on the size of the font characters, they are being drawn correctly. The problem is the space between the lines. What i would like to know, is the factor that i could multiply to the defined font size to obtain the line height to different font and sizes. The texblock depending of the font is giving an initial margin to the text inside the texblock (depending of the font) and also in my point of view is increasing the linespace between lines.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a value of `double.NaN` will use the `auto` line-height calculation mode which is what you want.